# WH_KEYBOARD_LL hook not called

Tags: c#, c++, winapi, visual-c++, hook

I'm having some problems with a `WH_KEYBOARD_LL` hook :

The reason why I'm using a global LL hook is not important I just need it for my app (I tried other types of hooks but they didn't work for me).

The hook function is in a dll, the dll is loaded on the application start-up and the hook is set also on start-up from the main thread. This works perfectly. The problem appears when I need to deactivate the hook and reactivate it back. If I do that from the main thread of the application it works ok , but what I need is to do this from a timer, and here things go wrong. I use the timer to check if my app's window is the foreground window (the active window), if so the hook is activated and if not the hook is deactivated. The return value of `SetWindowsHookEx` when called from the timer is always ok (not null) which according to MSDN means that the hook was successfully set, but my hook function never gets called.

Here is how I set my hook:

```
SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, keyboardHookProcedure,
                 GetModuleHandle(curModule.ModuleName), 0);
```

Has anyone ever experienced this??

My only guess is that my hook function is in a dll and the timer callback is from another dll, does this has anything to do with my problem??

Comment: Does the thread on which you install the hook have a message loop? A low level keyboard hook runs on the thread it is registered on, and requires message handling.

Comment: "This hook is called in the context of the thread that installed it. The call is made by sending a message to the thread that installed the hook. Therefore, the thread that installed the hook must have a message loop." This is different from other global hooks which run on the target threads and require dll injection.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: Oops -- You're right. I've deleted my misinformation. That does seem likely to be the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The hook callback is made on the same thread that called SetWindowsHookEx().  That bit of magic requires that thread to pump a message loop.  Which is the rub, your timer callback method is called from a threadpool thread.  It doesn't pump, it's not even around long enough to ever be able to get the hook callback.

Invoke to your UI thread or use a synchronous timer.  Or consider just temporarily disabling whatever you do in the hook callback instead of completely disabling or replacing the hook, that certainly makes most sense.

Comment: Deactivating the hook can be a good idea. Since it removes the requirement that every keypress is routed through your message pump.

Comment: Meh, be careful with a "it only sucks when it needs to work" mode.

Comment: thanks Hans Passant ! I also know now how I can actually disable a hook instead of just temporary disabling what i do in the hook function , but I'm to lazy at the moment and , I'll just stick to temporary disabling what i do in the hook function. I'll come back with a post on this

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I use `GetModuleHandle(0)` for SetWindowsHookEx in my code. I have no idea if this is your problem -- my code is single-threaded.

Comment: That will give you the module handle for the .exe that loads the DLL. Just clarifying your point.

Comment: Not sure if the library handle is relevant with a LL hook. For other global hooks it is required so the OS knows which dll to inject into other processes. But since a LL hook doesn't get injected, I'm not sure if that handle is ever used.

Comment: And using the handle of an exe makes no sense at all. Since an exe can't be simply injected into another process. So I assume it works in your case because the LL hook ignores it, but I'd be surprised if it worked with normal global hooks.

Answer (score 0):

You could check the foreground window in your hook function instead, and get rid of the timer thread altogether. That's what I do in TouchCursor. You can look at [my code on SourceForge](http://touchcursor.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/touchcursor/trunk/touchcursordll/dllmain.cpp?revision=8&view=markup) -- Line 553 for the hook function.

Comment: Two answers? Which one do you think is right? Would you like us to down-vote them both for a double whammy of rep loss?!!

Comment: @David: Whichever one solves his problem is right, I suppose. I didn't want to edit the first one, since it had got a bunch of comments about GetModuleHandle(). Seemed better to add a new one. Is this is bad etiquette?

Comment: it's mildly frowned upon to have two answers. Normally you'd just edit your first answer. You can discuss both ideas in one answer.

Comment: @David: Noted. I did look for a FAQ on this sort of thing but couldn't find anything.